# Json search for arbitrary fields

Tags: python, mysql, json

I am working with MySql+Python. I have a MySql table with json field. A user can store arbitrary number of fields in the json object.

For example:

```
{id:12, name:"a", age: 23}
OR
{id:5, distance: 23, distance_unit: "mile"}
```

Following query works great:

```
SELECT  JSON_EXTRACT(name, "$.id") as name
 FROM table
 WHERE JSON_EXTRACT(name, "$.id") > 3
```

However, it will only work when I know the field names beforehand. Is there a way to search arbitrary fields? Something like:

```
def search(json_field)
    magic!!!
    if (json_field==exist)
        return json_value
    else:
        return "not found"
```

I do not want to load all the results in memory and then search using Python as it won't be efficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you're looking to search the JSON data by **value**, without having to know its **key** (i.e. field)?

If so, you could try [`JSON_SEARCH`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json-search-functions.html#function_json-search) function. It returns the key name (field name) if a matching value is found, or a `NULL` if not. The second parameter of the function determines if you want to carry out the search on all the JSON fields or end it with the first match.

**Example:**

```
CREATE TABLE temp1(mydata json);
INSERT INTO temp1 values('{"id":"5", "distance":"23", "age":"23", "distance_unit":"mile"}');


SELECT json_search(mydata, "one", "5") AS success FROM temp1;  
-- Returns "$.id"



SELECT json_search(mydata, "all", "23") AS success FROM temp1;
-- Returns ["$.age", "$.distance"]



SELECT json_search(mydata, "all", "99") AS success FROM temp1;
-- Returns NULL
```

[Demo](http://rextester.com/MDEBA37773)

You could then perhaps check the value returned from the query in the Python code for `None`?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am not searching by value. There could be dozens of values that might match. I want to know whether a key exist in json object if yes then what's the value of it.

Comment: I think in that case `JSON_EXTRACT` does exactly what you want. For example, please have a look at this [link](http://rextester.com/WLKH42087). The query used is `SELECT TRIM(BOTH '"' FROM json_extract(mydata, '$."id"')) AS test_field FROM temp1` - it returns `5`. When the query is changed to `SELECT TRIM(BOTH '"' FROM json_extract(mydata, '$."id1"')) AS test_field FROM temp1` (a key that doesn't exist), it returns `NULL`, which can again be checked for in the Python code. What do you think?

Comment: Glad to know! :)

Comment: The query doesn't work for nested json objects :( For example, look at the link: http://rextester.com/VQKV1140 I shall know the path and level of nested field. Query returns null for "name" because I didn't provide the proper path.

Comment: Hi @Momi, If you know the level then it's actually a real good thing to have! The query can be modified slightly. For example, please have a look at [this link](http://rextester.com/HOITDW28556). If you know that `name` is at second level, then you'd use `json_extract(mydata, '$.*."name"')`. Likewise, if you knew that it was at third level, then the path would change relatively to `json_extract(mydata, '$.*.*."name"')`. Remember though, if your level formulating doesn't end at a point which doesn't hold any nested levels under it, then the remaining JSON string at that level will be returned.

Comment: Thanks! I might not know at what level the user would add a json field/object. Thus, I won't have level information. Is it a dead-end or could something be done?

Comment: I'm afraid, there's only so much what MySQL inbuilt functions can perhaps do (or may be if there's more, then I'm not entirely sure how). There are a few tricks mentioned on https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json-search-functions.html, but they'd all remain to be tried.